# Not able to load multiple ( 200+ )external jars from my /lib folder into my Sprirngboot maven/gradle project

Tags: maven, jar

I will need to load 200+ external jars( form my local harddisc) into Springboot REST project. Tried many approaches but none of them are working, Much appreciated if someone has solution.

Note: Please do not suggest mvn install or system scope as i need to construct artifacts for 200+ jar's which i dont like to do manually

Tried google add jar's plugin too its just copying the ${basedir}/lib/*.jars into my Maven target folder but not found in runtime.

Comment: There is probably something wrong here. You'll find most libraries on MavenCentral. It is unlikely that you have 200 libraries that are external (not from your company) and not on MavenCentral.

Comment: No we have one monolithic application which generates 200+ jars that i need to use them in other project, so no way those can be found in Maven central

Answer (score 0):

If your company works with Maven, it should run a Maven repository server like Nexus or Artifactory. When someone builds artifacts, they should be deployed to the Nexus/Artifactory and can then easily be read from there.

If this is not the case and you do not have a Nexus/Artifactory, you need to either install the JARs in your local repository (`mvn install:install-file`) or you need structure them in the standard repository layout (like `log4j/log4j/1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17.jar`) and import this directory as repository.

In any case, this will be a lot of manual work (as you already said).